# Symmetry-finding with SAGE?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-equations, symmetry, sage

On pp. 152-3 of Hydon's [*Symmetry Methods for Differential Equations*](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/ph282/sym.htm) (2000 ed.), he lists some computer packages for symmetry-finding. [This related Mathematica StackExchange question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20438/47125) mentions the [SYM](https://www.math.upatras.gr/~spawn/SYM_html/guide/SYMOverview.html) Mathematica package and Maple's [DEtools/symgen](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=DEtools/symgen). Does SAGE have anything similar for doing symmetry-finding?

<sup>[This question also posted on ask.sagemath.org](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36844/symmetry-finding/)</sup>

Comment: posted and commented/answered on: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174816/symmetry-finding-with-sage

Comment: and here : https://ask.sagemath.org/question/36844/symmetry-finding/

Comment: The Sympy library in Python claims it can use Lie's method for solving ODEs.  So, it would be in SAGE as well.   I don't know how well it is implemented but from experience it seems to be of limited utility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not specifically for SAGE (which is a conglomeration of several math packages), Dr. Willy Hereman's "[24 [symmetry-finding] software packages](https://inside.mines.edu/~whereman/software.html)" is a continually updated list of software (last updated: March 18, 2020).

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared algorithm in SageMath which finds determining equations for infinitesimals of ODE of order 2 and 3.
My paper is published on this with title "Determining equations for infinitesimal transformation of second and third-order ODE using algorithm in open-source SageMath" in Malaya Journal of Matematik.
The link for paper is https://www.malayajournal.org/selected_article.php?id=1007